# Accessing data with FEDERATED error #1429

Tags: mysql, database-connection, federated, federated-table

I am currently trying to establish a connection from one database to another on the same hostname(mysql.stud.ntnu.no) with FEDERATED, however, when the table is created(no problem), I get this errorcode beneath:

```
#1429 - Unable to connect to foreign data source: Access denied for user....
```

... being hostname and the rest.

I have checked that the mysql version is above 5.0, so it does support the FEDERATED function

Appreciate any help or tips you got on this =)

Comment: If it's on the same host, is there a reason why you aren't using `select column from db.tablename` instead of federated tables?

Comment: I was thinking about it, since I'm building it in Codeigniter. Might be a whole lot easier..
By the way, they are on the same hostname, but the logincredentials for the two databases are different(they contain different tables)

Comment: To select or join across databases, the user you are using needs access to both.

Comment: The user indeed has the right to perform those operations, anything else I'm missing?

Comment: If the same user is failing with a direct cross database query and with the federated table connection, I'm guessing it's still a permissions error. Can't really say for sure as I have limited insight into your setup (some sort of educational institute?) I would verify that the same user/password works from the command line to both databases. `mysql -h mysql.stud.ntnu.no database_name -u username -p`

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message before I executed this command on the remote (source) server:

```
mysqladmin flush-hosts
```